# How to transform each array of a list of array into a csv file

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I have a list of array saved as Array1 that consists of 3880 array, each array has 257 elements. I want to save each one of the 3880 arrays in the same csv file but each array I want to save in one row. Those are the first  array of the whole list of array:

```
[9.00000000e+00 1.02262955e+01 2.81256191e+01 1.08127435e+02
 7.49594020e+01 2.21052816e+02 4.21791240e+01 3.92422928e+02
 4.79340357e+02 2.06835979e+02 1.08237422e+03 9.09972312e+02
 2.86891627e+02 4.15947885e+02 2.00415374e+02 2.97422390e+02
 3.00102458e+01 1.30739760e+02 1.46960285e+02 1.20754880e+02
 ....... 5.00000000e+00]
```

In the CSV file, I want to have the whole array in one row along side the other arrays.

I tried this code:

```
np.savetxt("data8.csv", Array1,
              delimiter = "]")
```

and instead I got each element in one column like this:

```
9.00000000e+00 
1.02262955e+01 
2.81256191e+01
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that i understand your question correctly, in this case, i will assume that you want csv file to have the whole array in one row. My suggestion is that you can convert these data into the format of **pandas dataframe** first, then, save it as .csv file. You may try this code sample :

```
# suppose that you have a list that contains 3880 arrays named Array1
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Then, convert the data into format of pandas dataframe

```
# create a pandas dataframe with each array as a row
df = pd.DataFrame(Array1)
```

with this, suppose that we have 3 arrays which their values are `np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`, `np.array([6,7,8,9,10])` and `np.array([11,12,13,14,15])`. Here is a result where each array relies on each row in the dataframe

```
    0   1   2   3   4
   -------------------
0 |  1   2   3   4   5 # row 1
1 |  6   7   8   9  10 # row 2
2 | 11  12  13  14  15 # row 3
```

After that, save this data as .csv file

```
# save the existing data as .csv file (note that you must specify the path correctly)
df.to_csv('dataset.csv', index=False)
```

You should specify path that you want to save as well, here is an example when you want to save .csv file in Google Colab. You must specify an appropriate path in order to save it.

```
# to specify the data path, in google colab
df.to_csv('/content/dataset.csv', index=False)
```

However, always note that this is what i understand about your question, if i mislead something in your question. It is better to specify an example of format that you want your output to be so that i could come up with things that help you better

Good luck !

Comment: hey thanks for the reply . Actually after i use df = pd.DataFrame(Array1) i ended up with the array in a vector like this 9.00000000e+00 
1.02262955e+01 
2.81256191e+01 .   I didn't end up with a table like you had

Comment: You can try this instead, suppose that your vector is vec = np.array([9.00000000e+00, 1.02262955e+01, 2.81256191e+01]). then,  data = np.array([vec]) to format the data before put it into dataframe, after that, df = pd.DataFrame(data) as the next step. then you can do df.to_csv('test.csv') for your final step and it will be saved this time.  I try it on colab and it worked. Moreover, for multiple numpy arrays, i think you know what to do if the single array works, the rest woud be fine!

Comment: what i really need is each array that has 257 elements say [9.00 .......till 5.00] that array i need it to be saved in one row then the next one say[4.00 ..... 6.00] in the next row in the csv file and it goes on i have 3880 arrays

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand your question but to save each array in the list as a separate row in a CSV file, you can use the csv module in Python. Here is an example code that you can use the following:

```html
import csv

with open('data8.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for array in Array1:
        writer.writerow(array)
```

This code will create a CSV file named "data8.csv" and write each array in the list Array1 as a separate row in the file. The csv.writer() function writes each element in the array as a separate column in the row, separated by commas. The newline='' parameter is used to prevent the addition of extra blank rows in the output file.

You can modify the delimiter used to separate the elements in the CSV file by changing the delimiter parameter of the csv.writer() function. For example, if you want to use a semicolon as the delimiter, you can replace the line `writer = csv.writer(file)` with `writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')`

Comment: hey thanks for replying i got the error 'iterable expected, not numpy.float64'